# How exactly does this REST method that creates a new object work?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, annotations

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have the following doubt related how Spring MVC handle a controller method of a example Spring MVC webapp.

So, in my example, I have this method:

```
/**
 * Creates a new Account, setting its URL as the Location header on the
 * response.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public HttpEntity<String> createAccount(@RequestBody Account newAccount,
        @Value("#{request.requestURL}") StringBuffer url) {
    Account account = accountManager.save(newAccount);

    return entityWithLocation(url, account.getEntityId());
}
```

I know that this method create a new account into the DB.

So it handle **POST** Http Request (representing an insertion operation) toward the URL **/accounts**.

The **createAccount()** method take 2 parameters:

1. **@RequestBody Account newAccount**: I think that it extract the **Account** object from the body field of the request. It should be in **JSON** format and then it is automatically converted into a standard Java object (instance of **Account** class in this case).
2. **@Value("#{request.requestURL}") StringBuffer url**: I think that it is the same thing of do somtthing like to:

   ```
    request.getRequestURL();
   ```

   And it contains the URL used by the client to make the request. Is it true? But why it put it into a **StringBuffer** and not into a simple **String**?

Then the method simply use a DAO class to persist the object on the DB and finally it return an **HttpEntity** object as result.

This **HttpEntity** is created by the **entityWithLocation()** method definied in the same class, this one:

```
private HttpEntity<String> entityWithLocation(StringBuffer url,
        Object resourceId) {
    // Configure and return an HttpEntity object - it will be used to build
    // the HttpServletResponse
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setLocation(getLocationForChildResource(url, resourceId));
    return new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
}
```

From what I have understand reading the Spring official documentation in this case this object represents the **HttpResponse entity** that consist of consisting of headers and body.

My doubts are about this oject are:

1. In my case it is setted only the heder with the **url** value (the URL used by the client to make the request) and with the id of the new inserted object. The body field of this **HttpResponse** is empty?
2. Why have I to return this **HttpResponse** object? For what is used?

Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @Value("#{request.requestURL}") StringBuffer url: I think that it is the same thing of do somtthing like to:
>
> ```
> request.getRequestURL();
> ```
>
> And it contains the URL used by the client to make the request. Is it true? But why it put it into a StringBuffer and not into a simple String?

Because the method [`HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) returns a StringBuffer, and not a String.

> The body field of this HttpResponse is empty?

Yes, it is, since the code doesn't populate it. You could simply use your browser to invoke this action and see the response returned.

> Why have I to return this HttpResponse object? For what is used?

You don't **have to**. But you may **choose to**. That is up to you. You should know why you return what you return. The intention of the programmer here is to return a HTTP response with no body, with a Location header containing a URL, and a CREATED status. That's the conventional thing to return after a POST in a REST application: a POST is used to create a new resource, and it returns the status CREATED to signal that the resource has been created correctly, and the URL of the created resource, so that the client can get this resource and check what it contains.

Comment: mmm ok but it eems to me that it don't contains the status but that by account.getEntityId() it contains the object id or not?

Comment: `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)`: that's what sets the status to CREATED (201).